# Selecting pair(including reverse order) with highest date value

Tags: sql, sqlite, datetime, greatest-n-per-group

I have a messages table like this
[Messages Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QJRkN.png)

I want to select each unique pair (including reversed order) with highest date. Therefore resulting SQL Select Statement would be like this:

```
from_id | to_id | date | message
1          2      13:06  I'm Alp
2          3      13:06  I'm Oliver
3          1      11:38  From third to one
```

I tried to use distinct with max function but it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use window functions:

```
select *
from (
    select m.*, 
        row_number() over(partition by min(from_id, to_id), max(from_id, to_id) order by date desc) rn
    from messages m
) m
where rn = 1
```

Note: counter-intuitively enough, SQLite's `min()` and `max()` functions, when given several arguments, are the equivalent of `least()` and `greatest()` in other databases.

Comment: Many thanks, this indeed worked! Would it be possible for you to explain your code a little bit?

Comment: @alpino: the trick is to build groups of records by pairs of `from/to`. So we take the smallest and greatest value of these two columns to build the groups. Basically, `1/2` and `2/1` end up in the same group. Then we just take the latest record per group.